# Change html content of DOM element and pass it on as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my html content as below :

```
<div id="divParent">
    <div id="divChild">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="sometext"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="sometext"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get html content of `divParent` div and pass it on as an html for printing purpose.
This I can achieve fairly simple way by `$("#divParent").html()`
I also need to change the anchor tag text.  Something like this for example `document.getElementsByTagName("a").attr('href', '')`
But I don't want to change the actual anchor element on webpage. I just want to pass the `divParent` html with changed anchor tag attribute.
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) element, which can be manipulate and passed for printing.

> Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

```
var cloneElement = $("#divParent").clone();
cloneElement.find('a').attr('href', '')
```